# Reverse FloatToStrF Result

Tags: delphi, formatting, delphi-2010, currency

Is there a function to reverse `FloatToStrF`?  By that I mean go back from currency money format to string format.  For example:

```
Edit1.Text := FloatToStrF(10000, ffCurrency, 15, 4);
```

The result

```
Edit1.Text = '$10,000.0000'
```

I'm wondering if there is somthing like `StrToFloatF` so

```
Edit1.Text = '10000';
```

thank's

Comment: I cannot actually understand this question. The reverse of `FloatToStrF` would return a floating point value. But you seem to want to return a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
function RemoveAnythingButNumbers(aString: string): string;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  for C in aString do
  begin
    if C in ['0'..'9'] then Result := Result + C;
  end;
end;
```

Note that I corrected the set of numbers.

Comment: from your answer i deduce that no StrToFloatF or somthing like even in newest delphi version thank's..

Comment: Do the pennies get upgraded to dollars?

Comment: What about decimals and minus signs?

Comment: Maybe Nicks code is secretly designed to help the New User achieve enlightenment sooner, by letting him discover how much he needs Unit Tests. :-)  The OP converted the pennies to dollars so maybe this is exactly what he needed.

Comment: Actually converted 1/100th pennies to dollars

Comment: David Heffernan yes i don't want to convert the pennies i rushed to accept the answer but it's i fine i can come with my own function...